# Difference between this two uses of MethodInvoker

Tags: c#, delegates, method-invocation

What exactly is the difference between this two uses of MethodInvoker:

1:

```
textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(b));
```

2:

```
textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { b(); });
```

I only understand, that variant 2 allow me to call b() with parameters if i want.
But what is the difference between this 2 versions?

Version 1 is clear to me:
I create a new delegate and pass it my b() method, which has the same return-type and paramaters as the MethodInvoker delegate. Standardcase of a delegate.

But what does version 2 exactly? What means/does here the "delegate" keyword?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

V1 creates a new `MethodInvoker` object and passes it your `b` method as a parameter. What the `MethodInvoker` then "does with b" is up the the class itself.

In V2 you create a anonymous method and cast it to `MethodInvoker` and do not instanciate any "additional object" and your delegate is executed "directly". Another even shorter way of calling this using Lambdas:

```
textBox1.Invoke(() => b()); // or .Invoke((Action)() => b());
```

In V1 you could also replace `MethodInvoker` with your own implementation, e.g. a `TryCatchLogInvoker` which does not execute `b` directly, but wraps it to logs exceptions happening "inside `b`".

Comment: Your example won't work as `Invoke` takes `System.Delegate` as parameter

Comment: I use it that way here and it works fine. Is this maybe WPF only, because there it takes a `System.Action`?

Comment: Yes, Try yourself with method which takes `System.Delegate` as parameter, compiler can't infer it, you'll end up with compiler error. You need to use `textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => b()));` or some other syntax.

Answer (score 2):

> I only understand, that variant 2 allow me to call b() with parameters if i want.

No, even with first version you can do it:

```
textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(b), parameter1, parameter2);
```

> But what is the difference between this 2 versions?

In second version there is an extra delegate to be called (and its body is just to call `b()`). There may be use cases for this (for example if you need a closures, see later) but in this case it has no meaning.

> But what does version 2 exactly? What means/does here the "delegate" keyword?

It's an anonymous method, if you check at generated code you'll see it's somehow equivalent to this:

```
void MyAnonymousMethod() {
    b();
}

void b() {
}

...

textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(MyAnonymousMethod));
```

As you can see it's pretty useless (in this case) because you add an useless expansive delegate call. It may be useful if you use it to *capture* variables:

```
int a = CalculateValueA();
textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    b(a / CalculateValueC(), anotherParameter); 
});
```

Note that this is pretty different than this:

```
int a = CalculateValueA();
textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(b), a / CalculateValueC());
```

Because of **when** function will be called and expressions evaluated. To understand all the implications see also MSDN for details about closures in C#. Same code hand-made will be much more complicated to write (you'll need to define your class to hold parameters/function calls). A quick inspection to decompiled code will make this much more clear.

Another common case is when you have to *adapt* e method prototype. It's not the case for `MethodInvoker` but you may want to call a method with - let's say - no parameters from an event (with `object` and `EventArgs` parameters). In this case you have some options:

- Create an event handler method with proper prototype then simply invoke the method you want.
- Create an anonymous delegate (like you did or with a lambda). Don't forget that anonymous delegate can't be simply detached from event handlers...

Comment: anonymous delegate? You mean anonymous method, right?

Comment: @user3415341 I saw both names all around but you're right _official name_ is _anonymous method_.